# Adding double quotes to a variable when creating a csv file in python

Tags: python, csv

```
    DudeNumber = 12    
    with open('innovators.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file,quotechar = "'")
    writer.writerow(["SN", "Name", "Contribution"])
    writer.writerow([1, "Linus Torvalds", DudeNumber ])
```

Output:

```
Linus Torvalds, 12
```

Desired output:

```
Linus Torvalds, "12"
```

DudeNumber wont always be a number, how do I make so I'm able to add quotes to the variable. Tried changing the quotechar but that didn't works. Not too sure on what to do. Using python 3 on Visual Studio Code

Comment: CSV data is string type by default; the first output is fine.  (but if you have a "smart" importer like pandas.read_csv and all the column entries have numeric form a conversion may occur)  (NOTE: spaces in CSV imply spaces in the data; you wouldn't really encounter either of these sample outputs)

Comment: Quotes are used to escape commas in csv, so if you have a single value with commas in it, you enclose that value in quotes. It doesn't make a difference when your value doesn't have commas. When you read the csv file using the csv module, it gets read as a string anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `f-strings` -

```
writer.writerow([1, "Linus Torvalds", f'"{DudeNumber}"' ])
```

This would wrap the `DudeNumber` with `"` and it would be written to the csv.

```
>>> a = 5
>>> print(f'"{a}"')
"5"
>>> print(f"{a}")
5
>>> print('"' + str(a) + '"')
"5"
>>> print('"{}"'.format(a))
"5"
```

Comment: Thank you it works!